# Curly braces disappear when trying to store a command into a variable

Tags: shell-script, set

I wanted to print a command after some manipulation and store it into another variable for further usage. The usage is something like this:

`source new.sh tmp`

Content of new.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

 set a = `cat $1`
 echo $a
```

My actual usecase, instead of `cat $1` is a combination of grep and sed commands.

Content of tmp:

```
hello world !!! {curly}braces missed
```

Current output:

```
hello world !!! curlybraces missed
```

Desirable output is to have curly braces retained, without changing tmp which is the input file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you’re going to have to show the actual commands you are using.

Comment: Is your interactive shell `csh`? Because `set a = ...` is csh syntax, in sh it would set the positional parameters, and not the named variable `a`. And `source new.sh` would run the script in the running shell, so the hashbang `#!/bin/sh` isn't used.

Comment: If you are running csh for scripts, please don't :P

Comment: `[ "$1" ] && a="$(cat $1)"; echo "$a"`

Answer (score 2):

```
source new.sh tmp
```

`source` runs the script with whatever your interactive shell is, so the shell set in the hashbang line `#!/bin/sh` has no effect, and is misleading.

```
set a = `cat $1`
```

This is csh syntax for setting the named variable `a`. In sh it would set the positional parameters (`$1` etc.) to `a`, `=` ... Since you're getting some value in `a`, it means you're either running csh, or you had set `a` before with something else in the interactive shell.

```
hello world !!! {curly}braces missed
hello world !!! curlybraces missed
```

And the braces getting lost is exactly what happens on my csh for an unquoted expansion:

```
% set a = '{curly}braces'
% echo $a
curlybraces
```

It's probably how csh deals with brace expansion Bash and ksh don't expand that with no comma inside, and Bash also doesn't expand braces after a variable expansion or command substitution.

So, in csh, it seems you'd need to quote:

```
set a = "`cat $1`"
echo $a
```

Not that I know anything about csh, so this might still be wrong.

Or, if you actually want to use sh, then it should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$(cat "$1")
echo "$a"
```

and you should run the script as `./new.sh` or such, without the `source`

(and preferably use `printf "%s\n" "$a" instead of the echo.)